# Nesting of CActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, yii

```
class SomeModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{some_table}}';
    }   

    public function getItemByParentId($parentId)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        //some criteria

        return self::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }
}
```

This method works properly when I call it from controller
SomeModel::model()->getItemByParentId($someVariable)

But now I have 3 very similar to SomeModel models, so I want to put common methods to one class

```
class CommonModel extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function getItemByParentId($parentId)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        //some criteria

        return self::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }
}

class FirstModel extends CommonModel
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{first_table}}';
    }
}

class SecondModel extends CommonModel
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return '{{second_table}}';
    }
}
```

But get error

> The table "CommonModel" for active record class "CommonModel" cannot
>   be found in the database.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

> ```
> public function getItemByParentId($parentId)
> {
>     $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
>     //some criteria
>
>     return static::model()->findAll($criteria);
> }
> ```

Comment: I've already tried but get "SomeController and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "model" :(

Comment: Method `getItemByParentId` you must placed in `CommonModel`. And from controller using: SecondModel::model()->getItemByParentId($id);

Comment: Than I can't understand where do you get class `SomeController`?

Comment: I can't understand too. But with "self" I get error from model and with "static" from controller :(

Comment: I had a mistake not SecondModel::model()->getItemByParentId($id); but SecondModel::getItemByParentId($id); This is why error was in Controller

Comment: Ok, for using SecondModel::getItemByParentId($id) you must declare `public static function getItemByParentId($parentId)`, but all must working. I made working example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zk8vnv374kfs7dh/TestController.php) - copy it in your folder "controllers" and try. For more details of error do this on the beginning of your index.php: `define('YII_DEBUG', true);` and `define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);`